# How to include jni folder of library project in build.xml

Tags: android, ant

my application have multiple library project ,during build I am facing 65536 method limit exceed error in my project, to solve this i am using ant for secondary dex,But when i try to run ant via command i am facing java/jni does not exist, after this i checked and found jni folder in my library project, i have searched on google but didnt get any success, So Can we exclude library project or can we add this type JNI folder in build.xml or any other way to do it
[image]

and this is my library project screenshot [image]